# Expected member name or `;` after declaration specifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm making an map view were I wanna zoom in automatic on users location, I have done the view controllers coding and are now on app delegate.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WalkingTableViewController.h"




@implementation AppDelegate

{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]


    WalkingTableViewController *rootVC = [[WalkingTableViewController alloc] init]
    [self.window setRootViewController:rootVC]

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]
    return YES;
}

@end
```

and I get `Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers` on the line

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]`

can someone help me please?

Comment: There almost no ";" in your code. Is it normal?

Comment: As your error says- u need to put ";" at the end of each statement.

Comment: I think he confused swift with objc

Comment: yeah, when i put in ";" i get more errors, so i deleted 3 or 4 and now have only 3 errors instead of 10 that i get when i put in ";". I'm a beginner so..

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. "What does this error mean?" it's basic but it's not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you need to end with `;` each statement. It delimits the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors here. As someone else said, it looks like you are mixing Objective-C and Swift concepts and syntax in the same file. .m means objective-C so...

You have a method implementation in your @implementation. @implementation is the class implementation and contains method definitions. Also, you need to add a `;` after every line to show the compiler that the statement is finished - like a full stop at the end of the sentence. So you should have:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    WalkingTableViewController *rootVC = [[WalkingTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rootVC];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

But I don't think you're done with the errors there. I think you should look at the basic tutorials before trying to display a map.

Comment: thanks! i did deleted the first line -(BOOL) ........... i think that was wrong of me.. so thanks again